# what is data length/size limit of json datatype in mysql 5.7

Tags: mysql

I am using mysql 5.7 for json type storage. I want to know what is the size/length limit of json data type in mysql 5.7.

I am trying to convert json object into json string and store it , but somehow it is ignoring it. So is there any way to store the length json string into json datatype ?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet

Answer (score 0):

According to [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html):

> It is important to keep in mind that the size of any JSON document stored in a JSON column is limited to the value of the max_allowed_packet system variable.

And according to [the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_max_allowed_packet) this is a Maximum Value of **1,073,741,824**. Note that the default value of `max_allowed_packet` is lower and depends on the version of MySQL you use.